# iOS Wave Effect Animated Bezier Curve

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-graphics, uibezierpath, cakeyframeanimation

I am trying to achieve an animation effect which will simulate a very simple representation of a wave effect by using bezierpath and keyframeanimation.

However, with key frame animation I cant get the effect properly, the animation is working from start point to end instead of making wave curves up and down.

This could be a better representation of what is happening.

[Bezier Curve Wave Animation](https://vid.me/Hphx)

and this is the code for the animation:

```
    CGPoint rightCurve;
    rightCurve.x = center.x + radius * cos(startAngle);
    rightCurve.y = center.y + radius * sin(startAngle);

    CGPoint leftCurve;
    leftCurve.x = center.x + radius * cos(endAngle);
    leftCurve.y = center.y + radius * sin(endAngle);

    CGPoint centerCurve;
    centerCurve.x = center.x;
    centerCurve.y = leftCurve.y;

    CGPoint controlLeftUp = CGPointMake((leftCurve.x + centerCurve.x) /2, ((centerCurve.y + ((centerCurve.x - rightCurve.x)/2)*1.3)));
    CGPoint controlLeftDown = CGPointMake((leftCurve.x + centerCurve.x) /2,  ((centerCurve.y - ((centerCurve.x - rightCurve.x)/2)*1.3)));
    CGPoint controlRightDown = CGPointMake((rightCurve.x + centerCurve.x) /2,  ((centerCurve.y - ((centerCurve.x - rightCurve.x)/2)*1.3)));
    CGPoint controlRightUp = CGPointMake((rightCurve.x + centerCurve.x) /2, ((centerCurve.y + ((centerCurve.x - rightCurve.x)/2)*1.3)));

    UIBezierPath* path0 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path0 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(leftCurve.x, leftCurve.y)];
    [path0 addQuadCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(centerCurve.x, centerCurve.y) controlPoint:controlLeftUp];
    [path0 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(centerCurve.x , centerCurve.y)];
    [path0 addQuadCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(rightCurve.x, rightCurve.y) controlPoint:controlRightDown];

    UIBezierPath* path1 = [UIBezierPath bezierPath];
    [path1 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(rightCurve.x,rightCurve.y)];
    [path1 addQuadCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(centerCurve.x, centerCurve.y) controlPoint:controlRightUp];
    [path1 moveToPoint:CGPointMake(centerCurve.x , centerCurve.y)];
    [path1 addQuadCurveToPoint:CGPointMake(leftCurve.x, leftCurve.y) controlPoint:controlLeftDown];


    CAKeyframeAnimation* animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"path"];
    animation.duration = _animationInterval;
    animation.values = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:(id)path0.CGPath, (id)path1.CGPath, nil];  
    animation.repeatCount = HUGE_VALF;
    [shapeLayer addAnimation:animation forKey:nil];
```

It will be amazing if someone tell me how to edit the animation or the curve.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So do you want the effect in that video? Or something else? Because you do not need to animate the curve to get that effect. You just draw the curve and animate a transform of the drawing.

Comment: No I have the effect in the video but I need a normal wave effect like peak points are going up and down